# open multiple instances of a (.pdf) file

Tags: bash

I would like to open multiple instances of the same file with some sort of command.  I've tried some very unsophisticated ideas (e.g., an `alias` or `function` in my `.bashrc`, a simple shell script), but they all open the file once, then open another instance after i close the first open file).

I know it's not a big deal to simply type an aliased command four (say) times, but it must be dead easy to write a command that would call, e.g.,

```
mupdf /path/to/file/file.pdf
```

four times so the file is opened four times all at once..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like that your approach is using sequential invokation of the commands. You need to **start** the programs **in the background**. In bash (use your own program instead of the fictional 'openpdf'):

```
$ openpdf something.pdf &
[1] 1234
$
```

The `&` symbol tells bash to launch the program in the background. You can type in other commands while the other program is running. If you repeat this n times then it will be launched n times. Learn more about job control in bash by consulting the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control).

Comment: I'll be damned.  I could've sworn that's what I did yesterday, but I must only tried `&&` and `;`.  I feel like a fool, but thanks anyway!

Comment: I should also add (in case anyone else makes the same mistake) that not all pdf viewers like opening multiple copies of the same file (e.g., `evince`).

Answer (score 1):

To open it 3 times, call it like this:

```
   for i in {1..3}; do xpdf some.pdf & done
```

An alias will not work for the general case, since you have 3 parameters, and aliases don't allow for parameters:

- N the number of times to run
- prg the program to run
- file the file to open with the program

So you could write a function to include in your .bashrc:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 xtimes () {
     for i in $(seq 1 $1); do $2 $3 & done
 }
```

You can't use {1..$1}, because in curly braces, there is no parameters expansion.